# Issues with stored procedure sql server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Hi Im trying to use a stored procedure written by the database administrator using PHP, when used the instruction sqlsrv_query i get a message error but I can't figure out what it means, Thanks for any help

This is PHP code:

```
<?php                               
 $var_Active = 1;                       
 $var_PersonID = 0;             
$var_StartWeek = null;                                              
    $sp_name = "{CALL sp_PersonAlerts_Get(@Activ0=?,@StartWeek=?,@PersonID=?)} ";
              $params = array(
                    array($var_Active, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_StartWeek, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_PersonID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
                  );
              $result = sqlsrv_query( $gaSql['link'], $sp_name, $params ) or die("<pre>" . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()) . "<br><br>$result</pre>") ;        
                    $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $result );  
                                    $var_StartDate = $obj->StartDate;
                                    echo 'date: '.$var_StartDate;
               ?>
```

The error message I get is this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 
[code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
[SQL Server]@StartWeek: 2017-09-17, @EndWk: 2017-09-23 '
[message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
[SQL Server]@StartWeek: 2017-09-17, @EndWk: 2017-09-23 ) )
```

Don't know what the message means,

Comment: did you try using `execute` instead of `CALL`?

Answer (score 0):

`CALL` is used for mysql but `exec` is used for sql server to execute to stored procedure. Also it doesn't require `()` for sql server. Here is the syntax for sql server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql

Alternately you can try following:

```
$var_Active = 1;                       
 $var_PersonID = 0;             
$var_StartWeek = null;     

$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$params = array(
    array('$var_Active', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array('$var_StartWeek', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array('$var_PersonID', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
);

$sp_name = "EXEC sp_PersonAlerts_Get @Activ0 = ?, @StartWeek = ?, @PersonID=?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sp_name, $params);

if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "Your code is fail!";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_rows($stmt)){
    $var_StartDate = $row['StartDate'];
    echo 'date: '.$var_StartDate;
}
```

Comment: I changed Call for Execute but it didn't do any difference

Comment: did you remove the brackets`()`?

Comment: can you try following code to check your connection?:   $serverName = "(local)";  
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname");  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  
if( $conn === false )  
{  
     echo "Could not connect.\n";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}

Comment: @ClaudioMartinez, i have updated code.  Please check

Comment: thank you for the code,  the connection is ok since I have used in other parts of the system but the result was: "Your code is fail!", where is the error in this case then?

Comment: can you please try following query in sql management studio to check if stored procedure is okay or not?: `EXEC sp_PersonAlerts_Get @Activ0 = 1, @StartWeek = null, @PersonID=0`

Comment: @ClaudioMartinez i have updated my code as well(now it will display the error message). let see the error message.

Comment: tried the new code the message shows: `"Your code is fail!Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]@StartWeek: 2017-09-17, @EndWk: 2017-09-23 [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]@StartWeek: 2017-09-17, @EndWk: 2017-09-23 ) ) "`

Comment: Did you try it in sql management studio?: `EXEC sp_PersonAlerts_Get @Activ0 = 1, @StartWeek = null, @PersonID=0`

Comment: We need to check if your stored procedure is okay or not?

Comment: Can you share your stored procedure in the post?

Comment: the stored procedure is: `DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[sp_PersonAlerts_Get]

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO`

Comment: I tried this `EXEC sp_PersonAlerts_Get @Activ0 = 1, @StartWeek = null, @PersonID=0` on Sql server management and it returned a resultset, but can't make it work with PhP

Comment: can you try following to see your php version?  <?php
    phpinfo()
?>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver  check the above link to check if your php and sql server driver version matches